# MVC3 :: Create a view to handle multiple types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a situation where I am wanting an 'Add' View to accept an int from the controller but return a different type to the HttpPost controller method.  Confusing, I know.  The 'Add' View is used to create an object typed as a Widget, but I need to pass in the ID of the WidgetCategory.  So in my WidgetController, I would have a method something like:

```
public ActionResult Add(int id) // 'id' is the WidgetCategoryID
{
    return View(id);
}
```

However, in the view, since in it's intended to return a Widget to be added would start like this:

```
@using MyProject.Models
@model Widget
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // Insert markup here ...
}
```

My question is, how do I pass the WidgetCategoryID into the controller if it's typed to return a Widget?  I was hoping to add it as a hidden field inside the form like so:

```
@Html.Hidden(id)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest changing the name on the parameter from `id` to `widgetCategoryId`. If you need a comment to tell me what the variable stands for you haven't named it well.

Comment: The fact that most of the answers assumed your `id` parameter on `Add(int id)` was meant for `Widget.Id` instead of `Widget.WidgetCategoryId` proves my earlier point that you need to rename it instead of relying on the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default model binder checks for request parameters by name and attempts to set properties on model according. If you need something more evolute, you can take a look to custom model binding. Btw, you can change your action to:

```
public ActionResult Add(Widget widget) // Widget class has one property named Id with public set
{
    return View(widget);
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult Add(int id) // 'id' is the WidgetCategoryID
{
    Widget widget = new Widget();
    widget.Id = id;
    return View(widget);
}
```

I slightly prefer the second form for creations, but I guess it's a matter of tastes

Btw, your view's form shall have inputs for each "important" property of the Widget object. (Hidden or text) via:

```
@Html.HiddenFor (m => m.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your ViewModel `Widget` has a `WidgetCategoryId` property

```
public class Widget
{
  public int ID  { set;get;}
  public int WidgetCategoryId { set;get;}
  //Other properties
}
```

Send that to the `Add` View (HttpGet)

```
public ActionResult Add(int id)
{
  Widget objModel=new Widget{ WidgetCategoryId =id} ;
  return View(objModel);
}
```

Now in your `Add` View, Keep that in a hiddden variable using the `HiddenFor` HTML helper method.

```
@using MyProject.Models
@model Widget
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Title";   
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.WidgetCategoryId);
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Now you will have it in your `HTTPPost` action method when you submit.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Widget model)
{
  //  check model.WidgetCategoryId and Have fun with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your view code, you're not only specifying that the view will *return* a `Widget` type, but specifying that the entire model for that view is a `Widget` type.  Basically, that data passed both *into* and *out of* the View via its `@model` is of type `Widget`.

What you can do here is to retain the strong-typing of the View to a `Widget`, but where you need to pass in simply an ID value (a simple `int`), you can use either the [`ViewData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata.aspx) or the [`ViewBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

For example, in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Add(int id) // 'id' is the WidgetCategoryID
{
    // All properties of a ViewBag are completely dynamic!
    ViewBag.WidgetID = id;

    // You're still returning a View strongly-typed to a Widget, but not 
    // actually supplying a Widget instance.
    return View();
}
```

And in the View:

```
@using MyProject.Models
@model Widget
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    // Retrieve the WidgetID from the ViewBag
    var WidgetID = ViewBag.WidgetID;

    // Do something with the WidgetID, for example:
    @Html.Hidden(WidgetID)
}
```

Note that `ViewData` and `ViewBag` are [very similar mechanisms](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Difference-Between-ViewBag-and-ViewData-in-MVC-3.aspx) by which "non-model" data can be passed into a view.  ViewBag is newer (MVC 3) and is based upon the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) features of C#4.0, whereas ViewData is the older method based upon a collection of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

In the Add Action in the Controller you can set a ViewBag property to the id and them in the View do html.Hidden() using the ViewBag property.  I.e.,

```
public ActionResult Add(int id) // 'id' is the WidgetCategoryID 
{     
   Widget widget = new Widget();     
   widget.Id = id;     
   ViewBag.categoryId = id;
   return View(widget); 
}
```

In the View

```
@Html.Hidden(@:ViewBag.categoryId)
```